# Where is SSAS headed?

Tags: ssas

I was just wondering if I am one of the few people in the world actually using SSAS, or is it prevalent in IT?  There are so few people posting SSAS questions and answers here. Right now I'm running into an issue creating a Data Mining Dimension (model name dropdown is blank) and when I Google the problem I get 4 results.  MS did not include it in SQL Server 2010, so is it going away?  Are people using PowerPivot instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SSAS is there to stay. Microsoft have a 3 tier strategy for BI :

- Personnal BI
- Team BI
- Organizational BI

PowerPivot is both for Personnal and Team, but SSAS is clearly in the Organizationnal slot. You can read all about it there :

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/analysisservices/archive/2011/05/16/analysis-services-vision-amp-roadmap-update.aspx